# Django 1.11.3: Has anyone worked with JavaScriptCatalog?

Tags: django

Does it work? I do according to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/#module-django.views.i18n)

settings.py

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('ru', _('Russian')),
]
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^jsi18n/$', JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(), name='javascript-catalog'),
)
```

shell

```
django-admin makemessages -l ru
```

I'm added translation into locale\ru\LC_MESSAGES\django.po

shell

```
django-admin makemessages -d djangojs -l ru
django-admin compilemessages
```

But the response from the http://127.0.0.1:8000/ru/jsi18n/ does not contains translate from locale\ru\LC_MESSAGES\django.po

Am I doing something wrong? Or is it a bug in the JavaScriptCatalog?

Comment: did you ever resolve this? The documentation for this is seriously lacking

Comment: Unfortunately no. I wrote to the developers and the Django forum, they pointed to the tests in Django. No one answered in essence.

Comment: I followed this and it worked perfectly
http://joaoventura.net/blog/2016/django-translation-3/

Comment: I tried to pass po/mo file name to JavaScriptCatalog and it worked. It was "django.po" so I add it as JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(domain="django")

Answer (score 4):

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#makemessages

```
--domain DOMAIN, -d DOMAIN .  
Specifies the domain of the messages files.    
Supported options are:   
django for all *.py, *.html and *.txt files (default) .  
djangojs for *.js files
```

When you generate PO files for JavaScript, you run something like:
`django-admin makemessages -l ru -d djangojs`

This **only** generates the translation stubs for **JavaScript** (**djangojs.po**, it will search JavaScript code for gettext and other relevant functions to get "msgid"s). After compiling with "compilemessages", you get **djangojs.mo** files.

Serving with:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^jsi18n/$', JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(), name='javascript-catalog'),
]
```

will successfully translate **gettext** calls since the default domain is "djangojs". If you pass `domain=django`, translations in django.mo files will be loaded instead, but this is probably not the intended way to use it.